# Is there a way to automate testing Apple Pay in Java using Appium?

Tags: ios, testing, mobile, automation, applepay

I'm trying to automate testing Apple Pay on a food delivery app using Appium in Java and it seems that it can only be tested manually through sandbox tester. I tried searching for an automation solution but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appium uses the Apple XCUITest driver for UI test automation, but Apple restricts access to these controls even for its own tool. So this is not possible, unfortunately.